# Feature request to create short domain url for SE sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

I would like to propose a feature request to assign a shorter urls and redirect them to the respective Stackexchange site.

#### Examples

- so.se --> http://stackoverflow.com
- meta.se --> http://meta.stackoverflow.com
- su.se --> http://superuser.com
- unix.se --> http://unix.stackexchange.com
- tex.se --> http://tex.stackexchange.com

The shorter url may be `.se` or `.se.com` or something else, if anyone has a good idea with that.

Do let me know, what you feel/your ideas about this?

Comment: [Perhaps this will be helpful -](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk). Is http://s.tk/so short enough? ;)

Comment: The shortened URLs question is certainly helpful, but this is really a __duplicate__ of [Can Stack Overflow, Inc. purchase the .se top-level domain?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/can-stackoverflow-inc-purchase-the-se-top-level-domain) Also related: [stackexchange.com is too long; can we have something shorter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115523/stackexchange-com-is-too-long-can-we-have-something-shorter?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been done, but not though the .se domain as you suggested. The top-level .se domain is the country code of Sweden, and many of the URLs you suggest are no longer available. We use the s.tk domain paths as a shortener.

I won't duplicate that list here. Better to get it from the source:

[**What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)