# Can the Apple.SE magic comment link's title be changed to "Ask Different"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

Those [magic comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) are awesome, especially when commenting on reasonably good but off-topic questions.

Due to the tags I hang out in, I use the `[Apple.SE]` link more often than most others. Its title in the comment is "Apple". That is,

```
This isn't really a programming question. You might want to look into 
asking on either [Apple.SE] or [SU].
```

turns into:

> This isn't really a programming question. You might want to look into asking on either [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

which (if I didn't know better) would make me think that the commenter was linking to Apple's actual website, maybe one of their own support forums.

Could the name of the link be changed to "Ask Different", which is, after all, the name of the SE site? Granted that it's a minor issue (reader can just mouseover/click the link), but I think this would clarify communication.

Comment: I didn't know about these magic links!

Comment: FWIW Judiasm comes up as "Jewish Life and Learning" not Mi Yodeya which they are now offically called

Comment: @BenBrocka Not anymore: `[Judaism.SE] [meta.Judaism.SE]` → [Judaism.SE] [meta.Judaism.SE]. It now has the name *for real*.

Comment: Interesting. Then Ask Different/Apple is the only different one. ...magic comment different.

Comment: [Cooking.SE] should be Seasoned Advice. [Stats.SE] should be Cross Validated. It is not only [Apple.SE]^H^H^H^H^H [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com). See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/a-plea-for-actual-domain-identities

Comment: @VxJasonxV fixed ^_^

Comment: Well, that's one problem down.

Comment: @VxJasonxV That looks weird now. ;) *"Seasoned Advice should be Seasoned Advice. Cross Validated should be Cross Validated."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Praise Atwood, this has now been implemented (including the ones mentioned by others in the comments)! Can I get a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: `[apple.se]` = [apple.se] - looks like it checks out.

Comment: Yup; [VxJasonxV's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131854/can-the-apple-se-magic-comment-links-title-be-changed-to-ask-different#comment364925_131854) above used to look like: `Cooking should be Seasoned Advice...`