# Why in the footer some sites have first level domain (.com) and others do not?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Such as stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com, superuser.com.

I can see that those sites have their own domain names, so my guess that's the reason. But askubuntu.com also has it's own domain name, yet not in the footer.

P.S. There are others, stackapps.com, etc.

Comment: SO, SF and SU are the "trilogy" sites, they came first. Gaming, (arqade), Apple (ask different) may have their own domains but it's better to have their site topic in the footer because if you see Arquade, Ask Different, Ask Ubuntu, it's not instantly clear of the sites topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [A Plea For Actual Domain Identities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/a-plea-for-actual-domain-identities).

Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault are part of the initial "trilogy" of sites. So they got their own domain names. StackApps got a domain similarly, since it's not exactly an SE network Q&A site in the normal sense (just a site hosted and maintained by SEI, using the SE engine). AskUbuntu is part of a partnership between SEI and Canonical. Onstartups Answers is an SE 1.0 site being migrated over to SE 2.0 (See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) -- SE 1.0 sites bought the software and used it, SE 2.0 sites are created democratically via [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)).

So really, the domain names are for special cases.

Note that some sites have domain redirects, for example http://arqade.com (Gaming.SE) , http://seasonedadvice.com (Cooking.SE), http://askdifferent.com (Apple.SE), http://nothingtoinstall.com (Webapps.SE).